# How to count amount of results in Postgresql ignoring one to many join

Tags: postgresql

I have a pretty big query with multiple joins, and I need to make also a query with same joins but without `limit/offset` functionality just to take a total amount of rows for pagination.

I'm going to simplify query here to single join and omit all where clauses.

I have 5 offers and each offer has 2 events.

**Main query:**

```
SELECT o.id                       AS "id",
       o.display_name             AS "displayName",
       o.offer_hidden             AS "offerHidden",
       o.offer_type               AS "offerType",
       array_to_json(o.countries) AS "countries",
       string_agg(distinct concat(COALESCE(e.event_id::text, ''), ',, ', COALESCE(e.event_tag::text, ''), ',, ',
                                  COALESCE(e.payout::text, '')), ';;') AS "events"
FROM offer o
                  INNER JOIN (SELECT e.event_id, e.event_tag, e.payout, e.offer_id FROM event e ORDER BY e.offer_id ASC) e
                                                                     ON e.offer_id = o.id
GROUP BY o.id
```

As you can see here I'm making `concat` and `string_add` for events to get a single record for each offer

**Count query:**

```
SELECT count(1) AS count
FROM offer o
         INNER JOIN (SELECT e.event_id, e.event_tag, e.payout, e.offer_id FROM event e ORDER BY e.offer_id ASC) e
                    ON e.offer_id = o.id
```

Here I'm trying to make a query lightweight as possible omitting all selects and using the only count, but I'm getting count 10 as each offer has 2 events (5*2 = 10).

Question is it possible to make count only by the main table, but still using data from joins for filtering/ordering?

**Updated:** I know I can add same `concat` and `string_agg` to the count query, but this query should be lightweight as it going to query all records with `limit/offset`

**Updated:** looks like I found a possible solution using `distinct`

```
SELECT count(distinct o.id) AS count
FROM offer o
         INNER JOIN (SELECT e.event_id, e.event_tag, e.payout, e.offer_id FROM event e ORDER BY e.offer_id ASC) e
                    ON e.offer_id = o.id
```

but not sure is the best way to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a semi-join:

```
SELECT count(*) AS count
FROM offer o
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM event e WHERE e.offer_id = o.id);
```

That will be faster than using `DISTINCT`.